# Not empty in if condition

Tags: excel, vba

Here , var3 is empty but in the below condition **not empty condition** satisfies(which should not, because var3 is empty) and it goes inside the IF condition.
I tried with Not IsEmpty method and also with var3 = "" in if condition.
Can someone pls guide in this why its getting passed inside if condition.

```
If Not IsNull(var3) Or Not IsEmpty(var3) Then
MsgBox "Test"
oDoc.InsertDocument (insert_path2)
End If
```

Comment: Your condition will always evaluate to true as 'not IsNull(empty)' is True.  I suspect the test you want is really 'If Not IsNull(var3) and Not IsEmpty(var3) then'

Comment: I also tried to get my head around this one. The top answer here explains it well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32489787/what-is-the-different-between-isnull-isempty-empty-and-an-empty-string-ie

Answer (score 0):

As this question is tagged with <kbd>Excel</kbd>, I believe it's related to cells, being empty or not. There there seems to be a difference between a cell, where nothing has ever been entered, and a cell, where something has been entered and deleted.

There is a simple way to overcome this difference: simply check the length of the content:

```
If Len(Range("A1")) = 0 Then
...
```